# client side value not taken in server side on using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I wanted to avoid postback in my application. I am using telerik radcombobox. As user selects value from   radcombo box, the selected value should appear in server side code for databinding for another radcombo box. My client side code to show value in telerik radcombo box drop down is:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="tCodh" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="tCod" runat="server" style="width: 185px;" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" >
    <DefaultItem Text="Select" Value="" />
        <Items>                                                
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Description" Value="Description" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Account" Value="Account" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Price" Value="Price" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Quantity" Value="Quantity" />                                              
        </Items>
     </telerik:RadComboBox>

       function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {            
               var item = eventArgs.get_item();           
                document.getElementById('<%=tCod.ClientID%>').value = item.get_value();                  
            }
```

here i have used hidden field to store the value selected by user on radcombo box. The value received on hidden field is to be send on server side.
the code to bind value to serverside variable is...

```
   public  List<TelerikCombo> TCombo_Values()
   {
       string value =   tCodh.Value;        
   }

    But selected value is not shown. Instead error, object reference is not set to instance of an object is shown. Any help?
    Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is postback? All I know is that it's a .NET concept.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. You are storing selected value of a RadComboBox inside a hidden field to avoid a postback then you are retrieving this value only from codebehind. You can do this by tCod.SelectedValue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the hidden field value properly, there is a missing "h" at the end of its ID.

Here is your code with this fix that worked for me:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="tCodh" runat="server" />
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="tCod" runat="server" Style="width: 185px;" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">
        <DefaultItem Text="Select" Value="" />
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Description" Value="Description" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Account" Value="Account" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Price" Value="Price" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Quantity" Value="Quantity" />
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="get values on server" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
            var item = eventArgs.get_item();
            document.getElementById('<%=tCodh.ClientID%>').value = item.get_value();
        }
    </script>
```

and a sample server handler to use that data:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data = string.Format("data in hidden input: {0}<br />data from combo: {1}", tCodh.Value, tCod.SelectedValue);
    Response.Write(data);
}
```

And here is a demo of using cascading combos: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx